# Flickering lights after dead short

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

Very specific scenario I'm trying to troubleshoot. I was installing a new smart switch with the breaker off. I finished the install and went to turn on the breaker. When I did, I heard a POP, though the breaker didn't trip back. When I got to the switch everything was working fine, but there was definitely a dead fault because I could see a tiny bit of residue on the back of the brand new switch and a slight burnt smell. I turned the breaker off and inspected and, sure enough, there was a break in the insulation of the existing wiring right where the burn marks were.

The odd thing is that, since that POP, lights on multiple circuits in the house have been flickering periodically. I twice tried resetting all breakers including the main one, but no luck. I replaced the bad wire and put a different switch in that box, but even when *that breaker was off* while doing the work we saw the flickering.

Could it just be a coincidence or could a dead short have caused the issue upstream? It's also possible something got jiggled loose in the box when I was turning breakers off/on looking for that switch's circuit before I started working. I also noticed the main breaker has a bit of play in it, though I didn't touch that prior to the POP and the lights don't flicker when I jiggle it. I also plugged my meter into an outlet and (so far) haven't seen a drop in voltage when the lights flicker.

I have a call out to an electrician but would imagine it could end up being an expensive detective job, so I'd love any theories/leads to go on.

Edit: As requested, below is a picture of my main panel. It's old and has a lot going on, not the least of which is the high prevalence of tandem breakers, some of them in spots not designated for their use. I'll add that this is a 2-family home, hence the "first floor" written at the top. But this IS the main panel on its own meter.

Full panel:
[image]

Left side:
[image]

Right side:
[image]

Inside door:
[image]

Comment: One theory relates to the new mini split heat pump system we just had installed. If the 40 amp breakers for that were loosened, could that cause flickering when they come on? I typically love how quiet they are but in this case it makes it tough to tell if they're kicking on at the same time as the flicker.

Comment: Loose breakers in the box _could_ be a symptom of having the _wrong_ breakers installed the panel. Please open the door to your panel and take a good, clear, focused picture of the faces of _all_ the breakers and of any/all labeling (especially that on the inside of the door), then [edit] them into your question. Someone here will be able to quickly determine if this is the issue or not.

Comment: @FreeMan thanks! Photo added. Need to go back and get the inside door when I'm home later.

Comment: The bottom two on the left are Cuttler-Hammer, while the one just above them is a QP. I can't make out the writing on the rest of them, but that could be part of the problem. I'm sure the electricians will be along shortly to confirm whether that's OK or not. Grab a pic of the panel's labeling, too.

Comment: Have you pulled the breaker and verified the breaker itself did not arc and is now the root cause of the flicker. Having a Murray panel with mixed breakers this is one thing I would check.

Comment: @EdBeal Didn't pull any breakers since I'm certain it arced at the switch, but still worth checking. And I've been intending to have an electrician look at the panel at some point. Now I have a reason!

Comment: My daughter had a circuit that was flickering and went out , my son in law when checking the breaker found it had been arcing similar issue alien breakers in the panel. that’s when they called me.  they have only had the home for a couple of years it ended up being a backstabbed receptacle but  the tab on the breaker had some damage I don’t think it had been properly seated and different brands may fit but have different thickness so it’s best to check, easy to do. Turn the breaker off  and rock it out arcing is usually very obvious.

Comment: No signs of arcing in the box. I changed out a breaker that was humming but found it was actually the track lights on that circuit causing that. Off and full brightness the hum goes away, but dimmed results on a hum regardless of the breaker. 

I do have some shared neutrals (ugh) on the tandem breakers. Any chance that's contributing? From what I know the shared neutral is OK if they're on different phases, so maybe worth shifting those to achieve that?

Comment: Alex dimmers designed to work with electronic loads usually have a adjustment to prevent the humming, if it is making noise throughout the entire range you need a different type of dimmer that is compatible with the type of load.

Comment: Seems it's the old track lights and not the dimmers themselves because it happened on two different types of dimmers regardless. I may try new specifically dimmable bulbs and if that doesn't work I'll need to replace the track unit power supplies. And somehow, after putting all those switches back together (cleaned up the wiring) the flickering stopped. I still don't think that was the cause though rather I think it's related to the state of my panel and I'm going to have an electrician take a look in general.